# running oracle imp / exp in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, oracle12c, oracleclient

After installing the oracle packages

```
oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

and

```
oracle-instantclient12.2-tools-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

with `alien -i`

I want to run the `exp` utility, but I got an error

```
root@localhost:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin# ./exp
./exp: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

root@localhost:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin# export
declare -x DERBY_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"
declare -x J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH=":/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1"
declare -x LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s"
declare -x LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
declare -x LOGNAME="root"
declare -x LS_COLORS="rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:"
declare -x MAIL="/var/mail/root"
declare -x OLDPWD="/root"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin"
declare -x PWD="/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_CLIENT="212.166.58.203 58642 22"
declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="212.166.58.203 58642 139.162.221.107 22"
declare -x SSH_TTY="/dev/pts/0"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x USER="root"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="10"

root@localhost:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin# find -L /usr/lib/oracle -name libclntsh.so.12.1
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
root@localhost:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin#
```

Comment: You've updated your question but your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is still wrong. I state you need the _directory_ **not** the file. It should be `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/` (note also the missing colon). I don't get pinged when you edit, but I can help if you comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally caused by your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable missing the Oracle libraries. You need to find the folder in which `libclntsh.so.12.1` sits and set this environment variable.

Hopefully it's in your Oracle install directory, in which case you can do this:

```
find -L /usr/lib/oracle -name libclntsh.so.12.1
```

The [`-L` switch of `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) follows symlinks. This is not the default behaviour, however, it's possible that `libclntsh.so.12.1` is actually a symlink to `libclntsh.so`.

If you can't find the file then you'll have to traverse your entire directory structure. It might be worth ditching the `-L` switch for the first time...

```
find -L / -name libclntsh.so.12.1
```

Once you've found the file you need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. As just a one off you can use:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/oracle/lib
```

Where `/usr/lib/oracle/lib` is replaced with the directory.

If you want to make this change permanent then the normal way on Ubuntu is to add a custom `.conf` file to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, see the question [*"Use shared libraries in /usr/local/lib"* on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib/67783#67783).