# Robot Framework Database Connection cx_Oracle

Tags: database, selenium, robotframework, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to database as shown below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Database Username}    
${Database Password}    
${Database Host}    
${Database Port}    
${Database DatabaseName}    

*** Test Cases ***
Data Initialization
    Connect To Database Using Custom Params    cx_Oracle    '${Database Username}/${Database Password}@${Database Host}:${Database Port}/${Database DatabaseName}'
    Disconnect From Database
```

However, I am receiving an error

> Data Initialization                                          | FAIL |
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

May I ask what this error might be from and any solutions to this.

Comment: This isn't a cx_Oracle connection so it's impossible to say for certain. However,  I'd check your [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains the Oracle libraries on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305766/458741).

Comment: Hi, can i have a more in depth explanation as to what and how can i find this lib.Thank you for your reply. @Ben

Comment: The answer I linked to has the actual commands to run to find it (assuming that this is the issue - first check the value of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable). Was anything about running those commands unclear?

Comment: sorry but i am not really sure where i should run those commands

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise on the server/container that you're running your code from.

Comment: I am on windows 7

Comment: Can you provide additional information on the platform you are using and the version of Python and cx_Oracle that you are using? It would also help to know that basic usage of cx_Oracle is working on your machine before adding this additional layer.

Comment: I am using RIDE to code currently.
Robotframework 2.8.3
DatabaseLibrary 1.0.1
cx_Oracle 6.1
@AnthonyTuininga

Comment: Can you use cx_Oracle directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DatabaseLibrary [requires](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/) database API 2.0 libraries that need to be installed. The cx_Oracle module dll you can find them [here](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/).